# Flasch cs4 - Action Script 3 - why new URLRequest doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, actionscript-3, flash, urlrequest, navigatetourl

I heave a map in Flash, and some cities are a button.
When you click in the button, open the webpage of the city.

This is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

MovieClip(root).ammvi_amp.mun_bvr_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, abreURLbvr);

function abreURLbvr(obj:MouseEvent):void{
    var button:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(obj.target);
    trace('Fui clicado: ' + button.name);

    var request = new URLRequest("http://camarabotuvera.sc.gov.br/");
    navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
    MovieClip(root).ammvi_amp.gotoAndPlay(18);
}//abreURLbvr*/


MovieClip(root).ammvi_amp.bt_voltar_ammvi.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, reduzAmmvi);

function reduzAmmvi(obj:MouseEvent):void{
    MovieClip(root).ammvi_amp.gotoAndPlay(20);
}//reduzAmures*/

----------

stop();
```

#### The problem is

- in the Chrome,  navigateToURL dont work.
- in The SWF (open with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in Flash) and the exe, works.
- in some PCs, the swf and exe opens Firefox.

Why this?

---

*I saved the files in Google Drive:
[RAR (With swf, html and exe)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwEqvrpf-cBMR2ZXUXZ0TkRfWVE)*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Publish Settings ... Local playback: **access network only**

[image]